# DocuSign GET tab information from Completed Envelope

Tags: get, docusignapi

I've configured Microsoft PowerAutomate which collects information, pushes it through to DocuSign via POST using custom tab fields within a template.  This step works perfectly fine.

My next step is to collect the data that has been populated against the "completed" envelope and then push that information into a SharePoint List.

The problem I'm having is when I try and pull the data from the completed Envelope, I can't see the custom data i've had populated.

I've tried using "Get Envelope Custom Filds but only receive the below information:

```
{
    "textCustomFields": [
        {
            "fieldId": "215605",
            "name": "AppName",
            "show": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "value": "DocuSignIt"
        },
        {
            "fieldId": "215605",
            "name": "PlatformName",
            "show": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "value": "docusignweb"
        }
    ],
    "listCustomFields": []
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to collect the data from these custom tabs?

Many thanks

Comment: If your question was answered, be sure to accept it below! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Tabs (or Form Data) from an envelope, I'd recommend the [Envelopes::Get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get) method with the `include` parameter set to `recipients,tabs`.

So, GET `/accounts/[account_id]/envelopes/[envelope_id]?include=recipients,tabs`. As long as you're only making this call once the envelope is complete, polling restrictions won't be a concern.

If you would be making this call repeatedly to check for status, Matthew's solution of implementing Connect would be better overall.

Comment: Thanks for the information (and sorry for the delay), I'll test this out and get back and confirm asap!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, worked a treat - fields are coming back as epected!

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only time you're calling GET on that envelope, see Drew's answer below...

However, If you're looking to call GET repeatedly, it is likely that you will [run into API polling limits](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/resource-limits) by employing your current strategy. "You may not exceed one GET request per unique envelope endpoint per 15 minutes."

Instead, I would suggest using the [Connect event notifications service](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect). It uses webhooks to notify your app when specific events occur, such as "Envelope sent", "Envelope delivered", etc.

In your workflow, all you would need to do is set up a listener that receives HTTPS requests from DocuSign. If you configure your connect instance properly, you will receive a notification containing the information you seek automatically. No individual GET requests needed!

Here is sample XML sent from DocuSign Connect that would be of interest to you. Notice the `<CustomFields>` element and its children

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
      <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
          <RecipientStatus>
            <Type>Signer</Type>
            <Email>user.email@address.com</Email>
            <UserName>User Name</UserName>
            <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
            <Sent>2010-06-26T09:19:18.883</Sent>
            <Delivered>2010-06-26T09:19:40.723</Delivered>
            <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" />
            <Status>Delivered</Status>
            <RecipientIPAddress>::1</RecipientIPAddress>
            <CustomFields />
            <TabStatuses>
              <TabStatus>
                <TabType>Custom</TabType>
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <XPosition>364</XPosition>
                <YPosition>52</YPosition>
                <TabLabel>Radio</TabLabel>
                <TabName>Two</TabName>
                <TabValue />
                <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
                <OriginalValue />
                <ValidationPattern />
                <RoleName>TestRole</RoleName>
              </TabStatus>
            </TabStatuses>
            <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
            <RecipientId>fb89d2ee-2876-4290-b530-ff1833d5d0d2</RecipientId>
          </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
        <TimeGenerated>2010-06-26T09:19:45.771206-07:00</TimeGenerated>
        <EnvelopeID>0aa561b8-b4d9-47e0-a615-2367971f876b</EnvelopeID>
        <Subject>CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates Test</Subject>
        <UserName>User Name</UserName>
        <Email> user.email@address.com </Email>
        <Status>Delivered</Status>
        <Created>2010-06-26T09:16:21.27</Created>
        <Sent>2010-06-26T09:19:19.01</Sent>
        <Delivered>2010-06-26T09:19:40.747</Delivered>
        <ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
        <ACStatusDate>2010-06-26T09:16:21.27</ACStatusDate>
        <ACHolder>ACHolder Name</ACHolder>
        <ACHolderEmail> ACHolder.email@address.com </ACHolderEmail>
        <ACHolderLocation>ACHolder Location</ACHolderLocation>
        <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
        <SenderIPAddress>::1            </SenderIPAddress>
        <EnvelopePDFHash />
        <CustomFields>
          <CustomField>
            <Name>Envelope Field 1</Name>
            <Show>False</Show>
            <Required>False</Required>
            <Value />
          </CustomField>
          <CustomField>
            <Name>Envelope Field 2</Name>
            <Show>False</Show>
            <Required>False</Required>
            <Value />
          </CustomField>
        </CustomFields>
        <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
        <DocumentStatuses>
          <DocumentStatus>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Name>Document_Name</Name>
            <TemplateName>radio parents</TemplateName>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
          </DocumentStatus>
        </DocumentStatuses>
      </EnvelopeStatus>
      <DocumentPDFs>
        <DocumentPDF>
          <Name>DocumentPDF_Name</Name>
          <PDFBytes>PDFBytes_Information</PDFBytes>
        </DocumentPDF>
      </DocumentPDFs>
    </DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

To get Connect setup, [check out this guide on the Developer Center.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect)

Comment: Thanks for the information (and sorry for the delay), I'll test this out and get back and confirm asap!